# How to say "take a joke" in German

Tags: translation, word-choice, word-usage, english-to-german

When pulling a prank on someone or telling a joke that could come across as offensive, usually we say "take a joke" or something along those lines. What is the expression for this in German?

Comment: Do you say that in advance? Could you also give an example?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> *insertJoke*. Das ist nicht ernst gemeint, *inserName*!

As 0x6d64 points out, the following two expressions are rather used when you say something you are serious about, but personally I think it is not wrong to use them in this case, too.

> Nichts für ungut *insertName*, aber ... *insertJoke*.
>
> Nimm es mir nicht übel *insertName*, aber ... *insertJoke*.

Comment: I downvoted this answer, because IMO "Nichts für ungut" and "Nimm es mir nicht übel" are not something you say before you make a joke, but before you say something which you are serious about. Example:
`Nichts für ungut, aber ich glaube in dieser Sache hast du ausnahmsweise Unrecht` funny how this fits here ;-)

Comment: I agree with you on that you use these two expressions rather in serious issues, but I think it is OK to use them before telling a joke, too.

Comment: I don't know if I'm completely off track here, but if you would tell a joke this way I think that I might be irritated. On the other hand: I also don't have a good way to signal "joke ahead" in German, and I also don't get the concept of getting away with offensive jokes just by stating "I know, it is offensive but relax, it's just a joke". But this topic about offending other/feeling offended can lead to a lengthy discussion, which I don't like to take part here.

Comment: It's been a while; I just came back to this question and agree with 0x6f64 that my answer is rather incorrect and irritating. Accepting miracle2k's answer would be better. Unfortunately I cannot delete my answer since it has been accepted.

Answer (score 13):

I would suggest *Spaß verstehen*, as in maybe:

- *Versteh doch ein bißchen Spaß* or
- *Man muss auch mal Spaß verstehen können*.

Answer (score 4):

> *Mit Humor nehmen*

This phrase is only being used though about jokes directed at the person itself. When the joke is generally offensive, "*Spaß verstehen*" would be a better choice.